# Pandas - Count frequency of value for last x amount of days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I'm finding some unexpected results. What I am trying to do is create a column that looks at the ID number and the date, and will count how many times that ID number comes up in the last 7 days (I'd also like to make that dynamic for an x amount of days, but just trying out with 7 days).

So given this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd



df = pd.DataFrame(
        [['A', '2020-02-02 20:31:00'],
        ['A', '2020-02-03 00:52:00'],
        ['A', '2020-02-07 23:45:00'],
        ['A', '2020-02-08 13:19:00'],
        ['A', '2020-02-18 13:16:00'],
        ['A', '2020-02-27 12:16:00'],
        ['A', '2020-02-28 12:16:00'],
        ['B', '2020-02-07 18:57:00'],
        ['B', '2020-02-07 21:50:00'],
        ['B', '2020-02-12 19:03:00'],
        ['C', '2020-02-01 13:50:00'],
        ['C', '2020-02-11 15:50:00'],
        ['C', '2020-02-21 10:50:00']],
        columns = ['ID', 'Date'])
```

Code to calculate occurrence in last 7 days for each instance:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

delta = 7
df['count_in_last_%s_days' %(delta)] = df.groupby(['ID', pd.Grouper(freq='%sD' %delta, key='Date')]).cumcount()
```

Output:

```
   ID                Date  count_in_last_7_days
0   A 2020-02-02 20:31:00                     0
1   A 2020-02-03 00:52:00                     1
2   A 2020-02-07 23:45:00                     2
3   A 2020-02-08 13:19:00                     0 #<---- This should output 3
4   A 2020-02-18 13:16:00                     0
5   A 2020-02-27 12:16:00                     0
6   A 2020-02-28 12:16:00                     1
7   B 2020-02-07 18:57:00                     0
8   B 2020-02-07 21:50:00                     1
9   B 2020-02-12 19:03:00                     0 #<---- THIS SHOULD OUTPUT 2
10  C 2020-02-01 13:50:00                     0
11  C 2020-02-11 15:50:00                     0
12  C 2020-02-21 10:50:00                     0
```

Comment: Your example only spans one week (after we groupby ID), so we can't see that the 7-day window is working right. Can you make your example larger, to test that?

Comment: @smci, good point. updated above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a rolling on `Date` with correct window will do:

```
(df.set_index('Date')
   .assign(count_last=1)
   .groupby('ID')
   .rolling(f'{delta}D')
   .sum() - 1
)
```

Output:

```
                        count_last
ID Date                           
A  2020-02-02 20:31:00         0.0
   2020-02-03 00:52:00         1.0
   2020-02-07 23:45:00         2.0
   2020-02-08 13:19:00         3.0
   2020-02-18 13:16:00         0.0
   2020-02-27 12:16:00         0.0
   2020-02-28 12:16:00         1.0
B  2020-02-07 18:57:00         0.0
   2020-02-07 21:50:00         1.0
   2020-02-12 19:03:00         2.0
C  2020-02-01 13:50:00         0.0
   2020-02-11 15:50:00         0.0
   2020-02-21 10:50:00         0.0
```

Comment: I tried to replicate the solution and it does not work. There is an error `ValueError: window must be an integer 0 or greater`

Comment: @DuyBui `Date` columns must be of `Datetime` type.

Comment: You can try the example (with code) as in the first post with your code. It won't work. And yes, the Date is DateTime `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`

Comment: Worked fine back then (accepted answer), works fine just now on my system. Make sure you have correct Pandas version. Check it out [here](https://www.ideone.com/PC545o) as well.

Comment: Sorry, I understand why it returned an error. I assigned it back to the original DataFrame while you changed the index of the newly created one.

Comment: The other solution (by Serge) in this thread works for me. However, `apply` is too slow. I am wondering if there is a better to avoid `apply` so that it will be more efficient

Comment: I actually create a new question as I haven't found a solution. Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71952088/pandas-rolling-window-to-count-the-frequency-fastest-approach)

Answer (score 4):

You do not want to use a `Grouper` on `Date` but a `rolling` window. A grouper will segment the dataframe in separate consecutive blocks of the required duration. As you want 7 days from each date, this is the job of `rolling`:

```
delta = 7
df['count_in_last_%s_days' %(delta)] = df.assign(count=1).groupby(
    ['ID']).apply(lambda x: x.rolling('%sD' %delta, on='Date').sum(
        ))['count'].astype(int) - 1
```

it gives as expected:

```
   ID                Date  count_in_last_7_days
0   A 2020-02-02 20:31:00                     0
1   A 2020-02-03 00:52:00                     1
2   A 2020-02-07 23:45:00                     2
3   A 2020-02-08 13:19:00                     3
4   A 2020-02-18 13:16:00                     0
5   A 2020-02-27 12:16:00                     0
6   A 2020-02-28 12:16:00                     1
7   B 2020-02-07 18:57:00                     0
8   B 2020-02-07 21:50:00                     1
9   B 2020-02-12 19:03:00                     2
10  C 2020-02-01 13:50:00                     0
11  C 2020-02-11 15:50:00                     0
12  C 2020-02-21 10:50:00                     0
```

Comment: ok that makes sense why it would have that output. Thank you for not only the code, but the explanation.

Comment: Great answer. Tagged: [tag:rolling-computation]. If the pandas doc doesn't adequately cover when you use `rolling` vs `Grouper`, a docbug is worth filing...