# Pandas - Count frequency of value for next/upcoming x amount of days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, rolling-computation

This is follow up to the question I had asked here: [Pandas - Count frequency of value for last x amount of days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60617509/pandas-count-frequency-of-value-for-last-x-amount-of-days)

I'm trying to instead of get a count in the last x amounts of days, I'd like the count to look at the ID, and count how many times it shows in the x upcoming days. So for example, how many times does ID A show up in the next 7 days, from the given datetime on a row? So it's like a reverse rolling count.

```
import pandas as pd




df = pd.DataFrame(
        [['A', '2020-02-02 20:31:00'],
        ['A', '2020-02-03 00:52:00'],
        ['A', '2020-02-07 23:45:00'],
        ['A', '2020-02-08 13:19:00'],
        ['A', '2020-02-18 13:16:00'],
        ['A', '2020-02-27 12:16:00'],
        ['A', '2020-02-28 12:16:00'],
        ['B', '2020-02-07 18:57:00'],
        ['B', '2020-02-07 21:50:00'],
        ['B', '2020-02-12 19:03:00'],
        ['C', '2020-02-01 13:50:00'],
        ['C', '2020-02-11 15:50:00'],
        ['C', '2020-02-21 10:50:00']],
        columns = ['ID', 'Date'])

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Desired Output:

```
   ID                Date  count_in_next_7_days
0   A 2020-02-02 20:31:00                     3
1   A 2020-02-03 00:52:00                     2
2   A 2020-02-07 23:45:00                     1
3   A 2020-02-08 13:19:00                     0
4   A 2020-02-18 13:16:00                     0
5   A 2020-02-27 12:16:00                     1
6   A 2020-02-28 12:16:00                     0
7   B 2020-02-07 18:57:00                     2
8   B 2020-02-07 21:50:00                     1
9   B 2020-02-12 19:03:00                     0
10  C 2020-02-01 13:50:00                     0
11  C 2020-02-11 15:50:00                     0
12  C 2020-02-21 10:50:00                     0
```

Here's how to get the counts of previous 7 day windows. I've tried this same code, but after resorting in descending order on date, thinking that just switching the order would work, but that's not the case. So I'm stuck on how to have the rolling window looking ahead x days instead of behind x days.

```
delta = 7
df = df[['ID','Date']]
df = (df.set_index('Date')
   .assign(count_last=1)
   .groupby('ID')
   .rolling(f'{delta}D')
   .sum() - 1).reset_index(drop=False)
```

Comment: A little nitpick: The criteria in the question says `show up in the next 7 days`, the expected result column name is `count_in_last_7_days`

Comment: Ah good catch. I'll change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method using groupby and apply. I have a feeling there may be a better way using groupby and transform but I've never used transform and am still trying to figure it out.

```
def f(thing):
    cutoff = thing.loc['Date'] + seven
    mask = group.loc[thing.name:,'Date'] <= cutoff
    return mask.sum() - 1

df = df.assign(count_in_next_7_days=0)
seven = pd.Timedelta('7 days')
grouped = df.groupby('ID')
for name,group in grouped:
    n = group.apply(f,axis=1)
    df.loc[df['ID'] == name,['count_in_next_7_days']] = n
```

---

Here is an alternative using numpy comparisons with broadcasting. Assumes it is sorted by date and `'Date'` are datetime dtypes.

```
df = df.assign(count_in_next_7_days=0)
ids = df.ID.unique()
for idee in ids:
    mask = df['ID'] == idee
    x = df.loc[mask,'Date'].values
    y = x + seven
    comparison = y[:,None] >= x
    counts = comparison.sum(1) - 1 - np.arange(x.shape[0])
    df.loc[mask,'count_in_next_7_days'] = counts
```

For `counts = comparison.sum(1) - 1 - np.arange(x.shape[0])` the minus one is for not counting *itself* and the minus `.arange()` is for not counting past dates.

Comment: this is great. Much better than what I was trying to attempt today. I was going to try to get the inverse of the date, then apply the method I had used before, then merge it all together to get the original datetime.