# Pandas Rolling window with filtering condition to remove the some latest data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

This is a follow-up question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72183457/pandas-rolling-window-to-calculate-sum-of-the-same-items-of-the-last-n-days?noredirect=1#comment127536402_72183457). I would like to perform a rolling window of the last n days but I want to filter out the latest x days from each window (x is smaller than n)

Here is an example:

```
d = {'Name': ['Jack', 'Jim', 'Jack', 'Jim', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jim', 'Jack', 'Jane', 'Jane'],
     'Date': ['08/01/2021',
              '27/01/2021',
              '05/02/2021',
              '10/02/2021',
              '17/02/2021',
              '18/02/2021',
              '20/02/2021',
              '21/02/2021',
              '22/02/2021',
              '29/03/2021'],
     'Earning': [40, 10, 20, 20, 40, 50, 100, 70, 80, 90]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
df = df.sort_values('Date')
```

```
   Name       Date  Earning
0  Jack 2021-01-08       40
1   Jim 2021-01-27       10
2  Jack 2021-02-05       20
3   Jim 2021-02-10       20
4  Jack 2021-02-17       40
5  Jack 2021-02-18       50
6   Jim 2021-02-20      100
7  Jack 2021-02-21       70
8  Jane 2021-02-22       80
9  Jane 2021-03-29       90
```

I would like to

- For each row, take the last `30 days` of the same `Name` - call it a window
- Remove the latest `20 days` of each window (i.e. only take the earliest 10 days)
- Calculate the `sum` on the `Earning` column

Expected outcome: (The two columns `Window_From` and `Window_To` are not needed. I only use them to demonstrate the mock data)

```
   Name       Date  Earning Window_From  Window_To   Sum
0  Jack 2021-01-08       40  2020-12-09 2020-12-19   0.0
1   Jim 2021-01-27       10  2020-12-28 2021-01-07   0.0
2  Jack 2021-02-05       20  2021-01-06 2021-01-16  40.0
3   Jim 2021-02-10       20  2021-01-11 2021-01-21   0.0
4  Jack 2021-02-17       40  2021-01-18 2021-01-28   0.0
5  Jack 2021-02-18       50  2021-01-19 2021-01-29   0.0
6   Jim 2021-02-20      100  2021-01-21 2021-01-31  10.0
7  Jack 2021-02-21       70  2021-01-22 2021-02-01   0.0
8  Jane 2021-02-22       80  2021-01-23 2021-02-02   0.0
9  Jane 2021-03-29       90  2021-02-27 2021-03-09   0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Easy solution

Calculate 30 days and 20 days `rolling` `sum` then subtract 30 day sum from 20 day sum to get the effective `rolling` `sum` for first 10 days

```
s1 = df.groupby('Name').rolling('30d', on='Date')['Earning'].sum()
s2 = df.groupby('Name').rolling('20d', on='Date')['Earning'].sum()

df.merge(s1.sub(s2).reset_index(name='sum'), how='left')
```

---

```
   Name       Date  Earning   sum
0  Jack 2021-01-08       40   0.0
1   Jim 2021-01-27       10   0.0
2  Jack 2021-02-05       20  40.0
3   Jim 2021-02-10       20   0.0
4  Jack 2021-02-17       40   0.0
5  Jack 2021-02-18       50   0.0
6   Jim 2021-02-20      100  10.0
7  Jack 2021-02-21       70   0.0
8  Jane 2021-02-22       80   0.0
9  Jane 2021-03-29       90   0.0
```

Comment: I tested your solution on a dataset of ~250k data rows. It somehow increases the size of the data to 14 mil data rows. When I debug, each s1 and s2 have around ~226k. However, when they are merged, the size goes up massively. It's strange because I also use `how='left'`.

Comment: @DuyBui I believe you have duplicate dates per `Name`? You can verify this using `df.duplicated(['Name', 'Date']).any()`

Comment: Agreed. There were duplicates that I forgot to exclude. After excluding them, it works. I also suggest that you should not reset the index. Instead, you should merge using index `df.merge(s, how='left', left_on=['Name', 'Date'], right_index=True)`. I tested it and it was always faster without resetting the index.

Comment: I also mark your answer as the correct one. Thanks, Shubham.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to rolling (may be faster):

EDIT: actually slower with OP's dataset.

```
df['start'] = df['Date'] - pd.Timedelta(days=30)
df['end'] = df['start'] + pd.Timedelta(days=10) 
df = df.set_index(['Name', 'Date'])
df['Sum'] = [df.xs(n, level=0).loc[start:end, 'Earning'].sum() 
             for n, start, end in zip(df.index.get_level_values(0), df['start'], df['end'])]

print(df.reset_index().drop(columns=['start', 'end']))
```

```
   Name       Date  Earning  Sum
0  Jack 2021-01-08       40    0
1   Jim 2021-01-27       10    0
2  Jack 2021-02-05       20   40
3   Jim 2021-02-10       20    0
4  Jack 2021-02-17       40    0
5  Jack 2021-02-18       50    0
6   Jim 2021-02-20      100   10
7  Jack 2021-02-21       70    0
8  Jane 2021-02-22       80    0
9  Jane 2021-03-29       90    0
```

Comment: I tested your solution and it's actually slower than the one posted by Shubham. On a dataset of 250k, your solution takes 100766 ms (while Shubham's solution takes 38995 ms (about 2.5 times less). However, Shubham's solution increases the data size to 14 mils, while yours keep the size the data to be the same.

Comment: @DuyBui ah thanks for letting me know! I did some tests myself but probably they were not representative of real use. I will add that to the answer