# Pandas window function rolling sum not working correctly

Tags: python, pandas, window-functions

I am trying to calculate a rolling sum of sales per customer for the previous 365 days and am almost there but some of the totals are incorrect and I'm not sure why.

I modified the function from this link ([Pandas Rolling window to calculate sum of the same items of the last n days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72183457/pandas-rolling-window-to-calculate-sum-of-the-same-items-of-the-last-n-days)) like so:

```
def sum_of_last_365_days(df: pd.DataFrame, identifier: str, timestamp: str, sum_col: int) -> pd.DataFrame:
   
    col_name = "sum_%s" % identifier
    temp_df = df.set_index(timestamp) \
        .groupby(identifier, sort=False)[sum_col] \
        .rolling('365d', closed = 'both' ) \
        .sum() \
        .rename(col_name)
    temp_df = temp_df[~temp_df.index.duplicated(keep="first")]
    return df.merge(temp_df, how="left", left_on=[identifier, timestamp], right_index=True)

df_test = sum_of_last_365_days(large_basket, "customer", "trade_created_at", "amount_for_window_calc")
```

and taking one customer as an example it returns the following result:

[image]

The problem with this is that some of the values in the 'sum_customer' column are incorrect. For example the value in the row for 'offer_id' 2690289 should be 14966.77 (if we sum up all the orders of the previous 365 days we reach this value) but instead it is 14186.93 meaning two of the orders from the 01/04/2022 are not being included in the calculation (14966.77 - (389.92 * 2) = 14186.93)

I added the **closed='both'** argument to the rolling method but it didn't help.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Delete `temp_df = temp_df[~temp_df.index.duplicated(keep="first")]`, because the post owner surmise one user only have one record per day.

Comment: This helped ,thank you! I changed it to keep='last' and it solved the issue