# Append unique group ids from pandas rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe with timestamps, which I have used [DataFrame.rolling()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) to find occurrences within a small time window (10 seconds), following [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71952088/pandas-rolling-window-to-count-the-frequency-fastest-approach).

However, I would like to add a new column with unique group ids for all the rows which occur within the same time window.

After running the accepted answer, my dataframe looks like this:

```
timestamp                user_id    count
2021-01-08 10:00:01      1          1
2021-01-08 10:00:02      2          2
2021-01-08 10:00:03      3          3
2021-01-08 10:00:09      1          4
2021-01-08 11:00:01      1          1
2021-01-08 11:00:02      7          2
2021-01-08 11:00:11      3          1
```

My desired output would be something like this:

```
timestamp                user_id    count    window_group
2021-01-08 10:00:01      1          1        1
2021-01-08 10:00:02      2          2        1
2021-01-08 10:00:03      3          3        1
2021-01-08 10:00:09      1          4        1
2021-01-08 11:00:01      1          1        2
2021-01-08 11:00:02      7          2        2
2021-01-08 11:00:11      3          1        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the reset in number with [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) and boolean not (`~`), then [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['window_group'] = (~df['count'].diff().gt(0)).cumsum()
```

output:

```
             timestamp  user_id  count  window_group
0  2021-01-08 10:00:01        1      1             1
1  2021-01-08 10:00:02        2      2             1
2  2021-01-08 10:00:03        3      3             1
3  2021-01-08 10:00:09        1      4             1
4  2021-01-08 11:00:01        1      1             2
5  2021-01-08 11:00:02        7      2             2
6  2021-01-08 11:00:11        3      1             3
```